# Ler cada Linha existente no StringBuffer ou String

Tags: java, algoritmo

Possuo um texto com o seguinte formato:

```
Data            Valor
20140901        278
20140902        248
20140903        458
20141004        545
20141005        125
20141106        1020
20141207        249
```

O mesmo encontra-se guardado num objeto do tipo `StringBuffer` e gostaria de ler linha por linha, alguém tem alguma ideia de como fazer?

**Nota:** Se houver uma forma de fazer igualmente com uma `String` será válido igualmente.

**O que já tenho:**

De momento, não possuo uma implementação propriamente dito, mas a ideia que tenho é de fazer um `split` (neste caso, convertendo o `StringBuffer` para `String`) e passar como argumento o caractere `\n`. O porém desta ideia é a "performance", pois pretendo processar linhas na ordem dos milhares.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tenho duas sugestões, mas para dizer qual delas terá a melhor performance só testando...

Nota: antes de começar, sugiro usar um [`StringBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) em vez de um `StringBuffer` - o primeiro não é *thread-safe*, de modo que seu desempenho num uso *single-threaded* certamente será melhor que o segundo. A sua API é praticamente a mesma, de modo que seu código não precisará ser significativamente alterado.

1. Usando [`StringTokenizer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html) (assumindo que `texto` é uma `String`):

   ```
   StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(texto, "\n");
   while ( st.hasMoreTokens() ) {
       String linha = st.nextToken();
       ...
   }
   ```

   O texto original será mantido intacto (ao contrário de um `texto.split("\n")`, por exemplo, que dobraria a quantidade de memória usada), e somente strings pequenas seriam criadas - uma por linha - de modo que no total o dobro da memória original seria usada.
2. Usando [`CharBuffer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/CharBuffer.html). Infelizmente meu conhecimento de `nio` é bastante limitado, não sei se consigo dar um bom exemplo. Mas o potencial do `CharBuffer` sobre o `StringTokenizer` é que não seria necessário criar uma nova `String` para cada linha do texto - poderia-se simplesmente ajustar a posição (`position`) e o limite (`limit`) do buffer para designar a "linha atual", e usar o próprio buffer como `CharSequence` (i.e. como se ele fosse uma `String`).

   O exemplo abaixo [funcionou no ideone](https://ideone.com/k1E0m8), só não garanto - como já disse - que é uma boa maneira de implementar (assumindo que `texto` é qualquer `CharSequence`, incluindo `String`, `StringBuffer` e `StringBuilder`):

   ```
   CharBuffer buffer = CharBuffer.wrap(texto);
   int inicio = 0, fim = 0;
   while ( fim < buffer.capacity() ) {
       if ( buffer.get(fim) == '\n' ) {
           buffer.position(inicio).limit(fim);
           // Usa-se buffer como se fosse uma String (i.e. a "próxima linha")
           ...
           buffer.position(0).limit(buffer.capacity());
           inicio = fim+1;
       }
       fim++;
   }
   ```

   Se não me engano, o `wrap` inicial cria uma cópia do texto inteiro, mas uma vez feito isso o mesmo pode ser descartado e nenhuma operação adicional de criação de objetos será efetuada. Ou melhor ainda, faça com que `texto` já comece sendo um `CharBuffer` - por exemplo lendo ele do arquivo de entrada diretamente nesse formato.

Reiterando, embora o método 2 *pareça* melhor, na prática a criação e destruição contínua de objetos `String` não deve ter um impacto demasiado negativo na performance - uma vez que as JVMs modernas utilizam um coletor de lixo eficiente nesse quesito. Além disso, outras cópias podem ser feitas inadvertidamente, anulando o benefício. Ou seja, pra saber qual é o "melhor", só testando...

Comment: Obrigado @mgibsonbr, parece que não tenho outra(a) alternativa.